# .NET default formatting of decimal

Tags: c#, decimal, string-formatting

Why have theses 2 codes different behaviour ?

```
decimal test = 53M;
var label = "Some thing " + test + " other thing";
Console.WriteLine(label);

test = 53.00M;
label = "Some thing " + test + " other thing";
Console.WriteLine(label);
```

Displays :

> Some thing 53 other thing
>
> Some thing 53,00 other thing

Comment: Because `Decimal` 'stores' zeroes. It knows they are different values. If you don't want that, pass the specific format you want to `ToString`.

Comment: What do you mean by "different behavior"? Decimal remembers the number of decimals it was assigned with, and this is used in formatting. The first value didn't have any decimals, the second one had 2, they are thus both doing the same thing, representing the stored value as a string.

Comment: If you want value being formatted, provide the desired format: `Console.WriteLine($"Some thing {test:f2} other thing");`

Comment: ok, i wasn't aware to decimal was storing zeroes. Strange behavior, but ok :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we consult *binary representation* of `Decimal`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.getbits?view=netframework-4.8

> The binary representation of a Decimal number consists of a 1-bit sign, a 96-bit **integer number**, and a **scaling factor** used to divide the integer number and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction. The scaling factor is implicitly the number 10, raised to an exponent ranging from 0 to 28.

(**bold** is mine, Dmitry Bychenko)

We can easily explain the *difference* between `53M` and `53.00M`:

```
 53M     == {Integer Number:   53; Scaling Factor: 0} ==   53 / 10**0 
 53.00M  == {Integer Number: 5300; Scaling Factor: 2} == 5300 / 10**2
```